# How to get performance monitor in SQL Server Mangement Studio

Tags: sql-server-2014

I just asked about performance monitor VS 2015 and got perfect answer. I wish there could be performance monitor available for SQL Server Management Studio  also. Is it available for any version of SQL Server Management Studio? If yes where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2014 inside "*Object Explorer*" right click on the root node (your SQL Server instance) and select "*Activity Monitor*" from the menu:

[image]

or use the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

or click the highlighted button in the toolbar:

[image]

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/open-activity-monitor-sql-server-management-studio) on Microsoft docs.

Comment: Thanks ...one very basic question ....please tell me , this activity overview is for every database object or just for queries and stored procedures?